# How to keep PowerShell window open after running a command

Tags: powershell

I am brand new to coding.  I made my first ever "script" with a menu of programs:

```
write-host "`n`n1 -> Firefox"

$Choice = Read-Host -Prompt "`nMake Selection"
if($Choice -eq 1){
    Write-Host "`nOpening: Firefox..."
    Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
}
```

Basically this but with more programs.  I want the PowerShell Window to stay open so I can open multiple programs one right after another.  Say I want to open Discord, Firefox, and a game right after each other.  Right now I have to open the script over and over again to open each program, very inconvenient.  I'm sure this is an easy fix but I can't find a straight answer on Google.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Assuming that you're calling your script via the the PowerShell _CLI_ ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+), pass `-NoExit` before the `-File` argument to keep the session open after the script exits.

Comment: Otherwise, you may simply be looking for a [`while` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_While) to keep prompting inside yours script.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, and apologies for the formatting error.